# wxWidgets: wxToolBar buttons have wrong size when pressed

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

I'm developing an application with wxWidgets, using wxMac-2.8.12 on Mac Os 10.8.3. 
I need to add a toolbar with radio buttons, each button having an icon. If i create the toolbar using the funcion CreateToolBar everything works fine, but since I need to add two different toolbars, one vertical and one horizontal, for the second one I'm using:

```
tools_bar = new wxToolBar(this, ID_TOOLBAR2, wxDefaultPosition,
        wxDefaultSize, wxTB_NODIVIDER | wxTB_FLAT | wxTB_VERTICAL);
```

Then I create the different buttons and add the toolbar to a sizer:

```
wxBitmap* toolsBitmaps[9];


toolsBitmaps[0] = new wxBitmap(icona1_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[1] = new wxBitmap(icona2_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[2] = new wxBitmap(icona3_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[3] = new wxBitmap(icona4_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[4] = new wxBitmap(icona5_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[5] = new wxBitmap(icona6_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[6] = new wxBitmap(icona7_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[7] = new wxBitmap(icona8_xpm);
toolsBitmaps[8] = new wxBitmap(freccia_xpm);

tools_bar->SetToolBitmapSize(wxSize(32, 32));

tools_bar->AddTool(ID_SELEZIONE, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[8], wxNullBitmap,
        wxITEM_RADIO, _T("Selezione"), wxEmptyString);

tools_bar->AddTool(ID_FONDAZIONE_SUPERFICIALE, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[0],
        wxNullBitmap, wxITEM_RADIO, _T("Disegna fondazione superficiale"),
        wxEmptyString);
tools_bar->AddTool(ID_MAGLIA_FONDAZIONI, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[1],
        wxNullBitmap, wxITEM_RADIO,
        _T("Inserisce maglia di fondazioni superficiali"),
        wxEmptyString);
tools_bar->AddTool(ID_LIMITE_STRATIGRAFIA, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[2],
        wxNullBitmap, wxITEM_RADIO, _T("Disegna limite stratigrafia"),
        wxEmptyString);
tools_bar->AddTool(ID_PUNTO_CALCOLO, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[3],
        wxNullBitmap, wxITEM_RADIO, _T("Inserisce un punto di calcolo"),
        wxEmptyString);
tools_bar->AddTool(ID_GRIGLIA_PUNTI, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[4],
        wxNullBitmap, wxITEM_RADIO,
        _T("Inserisce una griglia di punti di calcolo"), wxEmptyString);
tools_bar->AddTool(ID_LINEA_CEDIMENTI, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[5],
        wxNullBitmap, wxITEM_RADIO,
        _T("Inserisce una linea per i cedienti differenziali"),
        wxEmptyString);
tools_bar->AddTool(ID_GRUPPO_PALI, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[6], wxNullBitmap,
        wxITEM_RADIO, _T("Inserisce un gruppo di pali"), wxEmptyString);
tools_bar->AddTool(ID_PALO, _T(""), *toolsBitmaps[7], wxNullBitmap,
        wxITEM_RADIO, _T("Inserisce un palo"), wxEmptyString);

tools_bar->ToggleTool(ID_SELEZIONE, true);
tools_bar->EnableTool(ID_LIMITE_STRATIGRAFIA, false);

tools_bar->EnableTool(ID_LINEA_CEDIMENTI, false);

tools_bar->SetMargins(0, 0);
tools_bar->Realize();

wxBoxSizer* itemBoxSizer10 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

itemBoxSizer10->Add(tools_bar, 0, wxEXPAND, 0);
```

The result is fine, but when I press a button, the size of the bitmap changes, as it gets so small it's not even visible.

[image]

The same code works fine on Windows, and also on Mac OS 10.4

Is it a bug or I did something wrong? Is there an alternative way to create two separate toolbars in one window?

Thanks
Eve

Comment: You should really try with 2.9.4. There have been many changes, especially in wxOSX since 2.8 and any problems with OS X 10.8 (which didn't exist back when 2.8 was released) are very unlikely to be ever fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

On wxWidgets 2.8.12, open setup.h, find wxMAC_USE_NATIVE_TOOLBAR and set it as follows:

#define wxMAC_USE_NATIVE_TOOLBAR 1

then re-build wxWidgets. Note that embedded controls may be not working after that.